# JS Object is logged like containing an array value with no key

Tags: javascript, gulp, elm

Below is the log of an error object from within a gulp plugin. Note how the first 'element' is NOT a key, value pair, but just an array on its own. I've seen something like this before (can't recall where) and ignored it, but this time I need to understand the issue. What is happening here and how do I access the array?

```
{ [Error: ## ERRORS in /home/code/btsync/HTML/Elm/src/Main.elm #


]
  message: '## ERRORS in /home/....',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-elm',
  __safety: { toString: [Function: bound ] } }
```

I arrive at this by catching and logging the 'error' created by

```
_this.emit('error', new gutil.PluginError(PLUGIN, err));
```

and then

```
    this.on('error', function(err) {
        // console.log("$$$$", Object.keys(err));
        console.log("$$$$", err);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the actual code or something which generates this error?

Comment: That looks like some fancy formatting of the error object. I don't think Object Initializers in ES6 (or ES5.1) allow this.

Comment: Like you all, I was really disbelieving. But I've added photographic 'proof'

Comment: What about `console.dir` instead of `console.log`?

Comment: Your Gulp plugin sure formats errors in a weird way. Maybe you should look into that as the cause.

Comment: Looks like that's what `err.toString()` would give you

Comment: Yeah, this looks like the normal formatting of an [Error instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). It isn't an array, it's an object. You can log it's properties like any other: `console.log(err.message, err.stack)` for example.